# EEFileLoadException When Loading C++ DLL in Managed DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli

I have an unmanaged C++ DLL that I would like to call into from within a C# exe. I looked into the possible solutions, and it looks to me like the best thing to do is to use C++/CLI as a wrapper for the unmanaged C++ class. So I wrote a C++/CLI class that looks like this, and gets compiled into a DLL (I know it should have a destructor and a finalizer, but so far the code won't get into the Main function, so I excluded them for simplicity's sake):

```
#include <cppheader.h>

using namespace System;

namespace DependencyInterface
{
  public ref class DependencyTester
  {
  public:
    DependencyTester()
    {
      _class = new CPPClass();
    }

  private:
    CPPClass* _class;
  };
}
```

I then have a C# executable that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using DependencyInterface;

namespace DependencyTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DependencyTester tester;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try and run the code, I get the following C++ exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd5a9e5d in DependencyTest2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException * __ptr64 at memory location 0x0094ca58..
```

I tried to set a breakpoint on the first line of Main, but the exception is thrown before the execution reaches that point. If I hit "continue" (I'm using MVS 2010) I get this:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76d8c5e2 in DependencyTest2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000020.
```

Does anyone have any advice? This is on Windows 7 x64, and everything has been compiled for x64 including the C++ DLL.

Comment: I need to see the stack trace to make the call.  But first switch your debugger to managed mode so you can see the actual managed exception(s).

Comment: For gigantic C#/C++ solutions, one should make Visual Studio stop at the location where the EEFileException is raised. Open the "Exceptions Settings" window (in Visual Studio 2019: menu Debug->Windows->ExceptionSettings), right click the tree element "C++ Exceptions", select "Add", and type "EEFileException". Now debug your program, and check exactly at which part of your code the exception happens, this should give you a good clue. Probably a native DLL of yours is failing to load, for several different possible reasons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An EEFileLoadException indicates the executable cannot find or load one of it's dependencies. That can of course has different causes (path problem, mixing configurations, mixing platforms).

A good start is using Dependency Walker (make sure to use the x64 version) on your DLL's/executables.

Comment: Whoo, that took forever! Yeah, the problem was was with some library that my C++ library linked in.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where I was referencing a dll in C# project and that referenced dll itself had dependency on some other dlls which i did not include in my solution. The issue was resolved after i added reference to missing dlls in my solution. Alternately, you can copy missing dlls directly to application directory. Using Dependency Walker did not help as they didn't show the names of the missing dlls.